# Issue in querying the task assigned to user jBPM5

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, jbpm

I am querying the task assigned to a user using the task service provided by jBPM5. Am getting one exception which is occasional in nature.

The way through which I am querying the task is having one method which will invoke by taking the userId as parameter. I am using the human task service api which internally use its own mechanism to query the task assigned to user.

```
public List<TaskSummary> getTasksAssignedToUser(String userId) {
    TaskService taskService = this.humanTaskServiceHandler.getTaskService();

    List<TaskSummary> taskSummary = taskService.getTasksAssignedAsPotentialOwner(userId, WorkflowConstants.LANGUAGE);
    LOGGER.debug("TaskSummary found: " + taskSummary.size());

    return taskSummary;
}
```

Occasionally this method causing the runtime exception as mentioned below

```
 com.xxxx.jbpm.workflow.exception.WorkflowException: Could not commit transaction
    at com.xxxx.jbpm.workflow.impl.WorkflowManagerImpl.getAllTaskByStatus(WorkflowManagerImpl.java:161)
    at com.xxxx.xxxx.wsserver.impl.ui.FetchApprovalRequestsServiceImpl.getFileCurrentStatusInWorkFlow(FetchApprovalRequestsServiceImpl.java:136)
    at com.xxxx.xxxx.wsserver.impl.ui.FetchApprovalRequestsServiceImpl.getTaskListAssigned(FetchApprovalRequestsServiceImpl.java:104)
    at com.xxxx.xxxx.wsserver.impl.ui.FetchApprovalRequestsServiceImpl.getFilesToApproveOrOverride(FetchApprovalRequestsServiceImpl.java:321)
    at com.xxxx.xxxx.wsserver.uicontrollers.CorpController.getLatestFilesToApproveOrOverride(CorpController.java:111)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:601)
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:219)
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:132)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:104)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandleMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:746)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:687)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:80)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:925)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:856)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:915)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doPost(FrameworkServlet.java:822)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:647)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:796)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:728)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:305)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
    at com.centrify.dc.wbase.DCFilter.doFilter(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:243)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:330)
    at org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.invoke(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:118)
    at org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.doFilter(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:84)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    at org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter.doFilter(ExceptionTranslationFilter.java:113)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    at org.springframework.security.web.session.SessionManagementFilter.doFilter(SessionManagementFilter.java:103)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.java:113)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    at org.springframework.security.web.servletapi.SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.java:154)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    at org.springframework.security.web.savedrequest.RequestCacheAwareFilter.doFilter(RequestCacheAwareFilter.java:45)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.preauth.AbstractPreAuthenticatedProcessingFilter.doFilter(AbstractPreAuthenticatedProcessingFilter.java:94)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    at org.springframework.security.web.context.request.async.WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.doFilterInternal(WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.java:50)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    at org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.java:87)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilterInternal(FilterChainProxy.java:192)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:160)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:346)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:259)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:243)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:222)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:123)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:581)
    at com.centrify.dc.tomcat.ContextValve.invoke(ContextValve.java:32)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:171)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:99)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:936)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:118)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:407)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1004)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:589)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(NioEndpoint.java:1686)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:722)

Caused by: com.xxxx.jbpm.workflow.exception.TaskServiceException: Could not commit transaction
    at com.xxxx.jbpm.workflow.services.WorkflowServiceHandler.getAllTaskByStatus(WorkflowServiceHandler.java:160)
    at com.xxxx.jbpm.workflow.impl.WorkflowManagerImpl.getAllTaskByStatus(WorkflowManagerImpl.java:159)
    ... 68 more

Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Could not commit transaction
    at org.jbpm.task.service.persistence.TaskPersistenceManager.queryWithParametersInTransaction(TaskPersistenceManager.java:310)
    at org.jbpm.task.service.persistence.TaskPersistenceManager.queryWithParametersInTransaction(TaskPersistenceManager.java:317)
    at org.jbpm.task.service.TaskServiceSession.getTasksByStatusByProcessId(TaskServiceSession.java:1155)
    at org.jbpm.task.service.local.LocalTaskService.getTasksByStatusByProcessId(LocalTaskService.java:205)
    at com.xxxx.jbpm.workflow.services.WorkflowServiceHandler.getTaskDetails(WorkflowServiceHandler.java:176)
    at com.xxxx.jbpm.workflow.services.WorkflowServiceHandler.getAllTaskByStatus(WorkflowServiceHandler.java:157)
    ... 69 more

Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to rollback transaction
    at org.jbpm.task.service.persistence.TaskLocalTransactionManager.rollback(TaskLocalTransactionManager.java:77)
    at org.jbpm.task.service.persistence.TaskPersistenceManager.endTransaction(TaskPersistenceManager.java:110)
    at org.jbpm.task.service.persistence.TaskPersistenceManager.queryWithParametersInTransaction(TaskPersistenceManager.java:298)
    ... 74 more

Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Transaction not active
    at org.hibernate.ejb.TransactionImpl.rollback(TransactionImpl.java:104)
    at org.jbpm.task.service.persistence.TaskLocalTransactionManager.rollback(TaskLocalTransactionManager.java:70)
    ... 76 more

2014-09-11 03:31:05,549 [http-nio-8080-exec-3] INFO [c3p0.stmt.GooGooStatementCache]  - Multiply prepared statement! select task0_.id as col_0_0_, task0_.processInstanceId as col_1_0_, names5_.text as col_2_0_, subjects3_.text as col_3_0_, descriptio4_.text as col_4_0_, task0_.status as col_5_0_, task0_.priority as col_6_0_, task0_.skipable as col_7_0_, user1_.id as col_8_0_, user2_.id as col_9_0_, task0_.createdOn as col_10_0_, task0_.activationTime as col_11_0_, task0_.expirationTime as col_12_0_, task0_.processId as col_13_0_, task0_.processSessionId as col_14_0_ from Task task0_ left outer join OrganizationalEntity user1_ on task0_.actualOwner_id=user1_.id left outer join OrganizationalEntity user2_ on task0_.createdBy_id=user2_.id left outer join I18NText subjects3_ on task0_.id=subjects3_.Task_Subjects_Id left outer join I18NText descriptio4_ on task0_.id=descriptio4_.Task_Descriptions_Id left outer join I18NText names5_ on task0_.id=names5_.Task_Names_Id where task0_.archived=0 and task0_.processInstanceId=? and (names5_.language=? or (select count(names6_.Task_Names_Id) from I18NText names6_ where task0_.id=names6_.Task_Names_Id)=0) and (subjects3_.language=? or (select count(subjects7_.Task_Subjects_Id) from I18NText subjects7_ where task0_.id=subjects7_.Task_Subjects_Id)=0) and (descriptio4_.language=? or (select count(descriptio8_.Task_Descriptions_Id) from I18NText descriptio8_ where task0_.id=descriptio8_.Task_Descriptions_Id)=0) and (task0_.status in (? , ? , ? , ? , ? , ?)) and (task0_.expirationTime is null)

2014-09-11 03:31:05,581 [http-nio-8080-exec-3] ERROR [workflow.services.WorkflowServiceHandler]  - Operation failed

java.lang.RuntimeException: Operation failed
    at org.jbpm.task.service.persistence.TaskPersistenceManager.queryWithParametersInTransaction(TaskPersistenceManager.java:310)
    at org.jbpm.task.service.persistence.TaskPersistenceManager.queryWithParametersInTransaction(TaskPersistenceManager.java:317)
    at org.jbpm.task.service.TaskServiceSession.getTasksByStatusByProcessId(TaskServiceSession.java:1155)
    at org.jbpm.task.service.local.LocalTaskService.getTasksByStatusByProcessId(LocalTaskService.java:205)
    at com.xxxx.jbpm.workflow.services.WorkflowServiceHandler.getTaskDetails(WorkflowServiceHandler.java:176)
    at com.xxxx.jbpm.workflow.services.WorkflowServiceHandler.getAllTaskByStatus(WorkflowServiceHandler.java:157)
    at com.xxxx.jbpm.workflow.impl.WorkflowManagerImpl.getAllTaskByStatus(WorkflowManagerImpl.java:159)
    at com.xxxx.xxxx.wsserver.impl.ui.FetchApprovalRequestsServiceImpl.getFileCurrentStatusInWorkFlow(FetchApprovalRequestsServiceImpl.java:136)
    at com.xxxx.xxxx.wsserver.impl.ui.FetchApprovalRequestsServiceImpl.getTaskListAssigned(FetchApprovalRequestsServiceImpl.java:104)
    at com.xxxx.xxxx.wsserver.impl.ui.FetchApprovalRequestsServiceImpl.getFilesToApproveOrOverride(FetchApprovalRequestsServiceImpl.java:321)
    at com.xxxx.xxxx.wsserver.uicontrollers.CorpController.getLatestFilesToApproveOrOverride(CorpController.java:111)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:601)
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:219)
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:132)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:104)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandleMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:746)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:687)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:80)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:925)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:856)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:915)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doPost(FrameworkServlet.java:822)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:647)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:796)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:728)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:305)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
    at com.centrify.dc.wbase.DCFilter.doFilter(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:243)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:330)
    at org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.invoke(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:118)
    at org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.doFilter(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:84)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    at org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter.doFilter(ExceptionTranslationFilter.java:113)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    at org.springframework.security.web.session.SessionManagementFilter.doFilter(SessionManagementFilter.java:103)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.java:113)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    at org.springframework.security.web.servletapi.SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.java:154)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    at org.springframework.security.web.savedrequest.RequestCacheAwareFilter.doFilter(RequestCacheAwareFilter.java:45)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.preauth.AbstractPreAuthenticatedProcessingFilter.doFilter(AbstractPreAuthenticatedProcessingFilter.java:94)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    at org.springframework.security.web.context.request.async.WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.doFilterInternal(WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.java:50)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    at org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.java:87)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilterInternal(FilterChainProxy.java:192)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:160)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:346)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:259)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:243)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:222)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:123)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:581)
    at com.centrify.dc.tomcat.ContextValve.invoke(ContextValve.java:32)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:171)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:99)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:936)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:118)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:407)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1004)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:589)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(NioEndpoint.java:1686)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:722)
Caused by: javax.persistence.PersistenceException: org.hibernate.exception.GenericJDBCException: could not execute query
    at org.hibernate.ejb.AbstractEntityManagerImpl.convert(AbstractEntityManagerImpl.java:1235)
    at org.hibernate.ejb.AbstractEntityManagerImpl.convert(AbstractEntityManagerImpl.java:1168)
    at org.hibernate.ejb.QueryImpl.getResultList(QueryImpl.java:250)
    at org.jbpm.task.service.persistence.TaskPersistenceManager.queryWithParameters(TaskPersistenceManager.java:352)
    at org.jbpm.task.service.persistence.TaskPersistenceManager.queryWithParametersInTransaction(TaskPersistenceManager.java:295)
    ... 74 more

Caused by: org.hibernate.exception.GenericJDBCException: could not execute query
    at org.hibernate.exception.SQLStateConverter.handledNonSpecificException(SQLStateConverter.java:140)
    at org.hibernate.exception.SQLStateConverter.convert(SQLStateConverter.java:128)
    at org.hibernate.exception.JDBCExceptionHelper.convert(JDBCExceptionHelper.java:66)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doList(Loader.java:2297)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.listIgnoreQueryCache(Loader.java:2172)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.list(Loader.java:2167)
    at org.hibernate.loader.hql.QueryLoader.list(QueryLoader.java:448)
    at org.hibernate.hql.ast.QueryTranslatorImpl.list(QueryTranslatorImpl.java:363)
    at org.hibernate.engine.query.HQLQueryPlan.performList(HQLQueryPlan.java:196)
    at org.hibernate.impl.SessionImpl.list(SessionImpl.java:1258)
    at org.hibernate.impl.QueryImpl.list(QueryImpl.java:102)
    at org.hibernate.ejb.QueryImpl.getResultList(QueryImpl.java:241)
    ... 76 more

Caused by: java.sql.SQLException: Exhausted Resultset
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleResultSetImpl.getLong(OracleResultSetImpl.java:912)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleResultSet.getLong(OracleResultSet.java:440)
    at com.mchange.v2.c3p0.impl.NewProxyResultSet.getLong(NewProxyResultSet.java:2625)
    at org.hibernate.type.LongType.get(LongType.java:51)
    at org.hibernate.type.NullableType.nullSafeGet(NullableType.java:184)
    at org.hibernate.type.NullableType.nullSafeGet(NullableType.java:173)
    at org.hibernate.loader.hql.QueryLoader.getResultColumnOrRow(QueryLoader.java:399)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.getRowFromResultSet(Loader.java:647)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doQuery(Loader.java:745)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doQueryAndInitializeNonLazyCollections(Loader.java:270)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doList(Loader.java:2294)
    ... 84 more
```

I am unable to figure what is causing the above error and how can I resolve it?

Versions used –

1. Spring Framework (spring-core & spring-beans) - 3.0.6.RELEASE
2. Platform – Redhat Linux - 2.6.18-308.el5
3. org.jbpm artifacts version - 5.5.0.Final

**Updated**

This is how I am configuring the entity manager for jbpm task service

```
<bean id="oracleDataSource" class="com.mchange.v2.c3p0.ComboPooledDataSource"
    destroy-method="close">
    <property name="driverClass" value="${DB.ORACLE.DRIVER.CLASS}" />
    <property name="jdbcUrl" value="${DB.ORACLE.JDBC.URL}" />
    <property name="user" value="${DB.ORACLE.USERNAME}" />
    <property name="password" value="${DB.ORACLE.PASSWORD}" />
    <property name="minPoolSize" value="${DB.ORACLE.MIN.POOL.SIZE}" />
    <property name="maxPoolSize" value="${DB.ORACLE.MAX.POOL.SIZE}" />
    <property name="acquireIncrement" value="${DB.ORACLE.ACQUIRE.INCREMENT}" />
    <property name="maxIdleTime" value="${DB.ORACLE.MAX.IDLE.TIME}" />
    <property name="maxStatements" value="${DB.ORACLE.MAX.STATEMENTS}" /> 
    <property name="idleConnectionTestPeriod" value="${DB.ORACLE.IDLE.CONNECTION.TEST.PERIOD}" />
    <property name="testConnectionOnCheckin" value="${DB.ORACLE.TEST.CONNECTION.ON.CHECKIN}" />
    <property name="preferredTestQuery" value="${DB.ORACLE.PREFERRED.TEST.QUERY}" />
</bean>

<bean id="entityManagerFactoryJbpmTask"
    class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean">
    <property name="dataSource" ref="oracleDataSource" />
    <property name="persistenceUnitName" value="org.jbpm.task" />
    <property name="persistenceXmlLocation" value="WEB-INF/spring/task-persistence.xml" />
    <property name="jpaVendorAdapter">
        <bean class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaVendorAdapter">
            <property name="databasePlatform" value="${DB.ORACLE.DIALECT}" />
            <property name="showSql" value="false" />
            <property name="generateDdl" value="false" />
        </bean>
    </property>
</bean>
```

I am using the same data source (oracleDataSource) for one of my hibernate layer, does it make any difference here?

And here is my task-persistence.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<persistence version="1.0" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence" xmlns:orm="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence/orm" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"  xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_1_0.xsd http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence/orm http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence/orm_1_0.xsd">

<persistence-unit name="org.jbpm.task">
<provider>org.hibernate.ejb.HibernatePersistence</provider>
<mapping-file>META-INF/Taskorm.xml</mapping-file>
<class>org.jbpm.task.Attachment</class>
<class>org.jbpm.task.Content</class>
<class>org.jbpm.task.BooleanExpression</class>
<class>org.jbpm.task.Comment</class>
<class>org.jbpm.task.Deadline</class>
<class>org.jbpm.task.Comment</class>
<class>org.jbpm.task.Deadline</class>
<class>org.jbpm.task.Delegation</class>
<class>org.jbpm.task.Escalation</class>
<class>org.jbpm.task.Group</class>
<class>org.jbpm.task.I18NText</class>
<class>org.jbpm.task.Notification</class>
<class>org.jbpm.task.EmailNotification</class>
<class>org.jbpm.task.EmailNotificationHeader</class>
<class>org.jbpm.task.PeopleAssignments</class>
<class>org.jbpm.task.Reassignment</class>
<class>org.jbpm.task.Status</class>
<class>org.jbpm.task.Task</class>
<class>org.jbpm.task.TaskData</class>
<class>org.jbpm.task.SubTasksStrategy</class>
<class>org.jbpm.task.OnParentAbortAllSubTasksEndStrategy</class>
<class>org.jbpm.task.OnAllSubTasksEndParentEndStrategy</class>
<class>org.jbpm.task.User</class>

<properties>
  <property name="hibernate.dialect" value="org.hibernate.dialect.Oracle10gDialect"/>
  <property name="hibernate.connection.driver_class" value="${DB.ORACLE.DRIVER.CLASS}"/>
  <property name="hibernate.connection.url" value="${DB.ORACLE.JDBC.URL}" />
  <property name="hibernate.connection.username" value="${DB.ORACLE.USERNAME}"/>
  <property name="hibernate.connection.password" value="${DB.ORACLE.PASSWORD}"/>
  <property name="hibernate.connection.autocommit" value="false" />

  <property name="hibernate.max_fetch_depth" value="3"/>
  <!-- <property name="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto" value="update" /> -->
  <property name="hibernate.show_sql" value="false" />
</properties>
```

Greetings,
Mayank

Answer (score 0):

There seems to be an issue with spring and the entity manager that is created inside the task service, there could be a conflict there, you will need to check if spring is messing things up with that. Are you using the spring persistence mechanisms to store something else?

Regards

Comment: I have implemented a separate hibernate layer which is taking care of other CRUD operations, it is just sharing the data source object. I have updated my question kindly take a look.

Comment: Taking care of the CRUD of what?

Comment: CRUD I mean create, read, update, and delete operations of database which contains the other tables to run the application.